# If $E\subset\mathbb R^d$ has positive measure, then the set $E-E=\{x-y:x,y\in E\}$ contains an open Ball $B_{\epsilon}(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $E\subset\mathbb R^d$ has positive measure, then the set
>
> $E-E=\{x-y:x,y\in E\}$
>
> contains an open Ball $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ with radius $\epsilon$ around the origin
>
> $\textbf {Hint}:$ Use the continuity of $f*g$(convolution), with $f(x):=\mathbb 1_E(x)$ and $g(x):=1_E(-x)$

What is the sense of choosing $g(x):=1_E(-x)$ ?

$\underline{My Attempt}$

$f*g=\int f(x-y)g(y)\ dy\overset{?}=\int\mathbb 1_E(x-y)\cdotp\mathbb 1_E(-y)\ dy\overset{or\le} =\int_{E-E} 1dy$

So, $f*g=\int_{E-E} 1dy$

remains to show that the integral above is nonzero.

If $E$ has positive measure can we say it contains an open ball with radius $ar$(s.t. $a>1$)

let $g':=\mathbb 1_{B_{(0,ar)}}$ then $(g\ge g')$ $\Rightarrow$ $(f*g\ge f*g')$

and for $\lvert x\rvert<r$

$E-E=f*g\ge f*g'(x)=\int_{\lvert y\rvert<ar} f(x-y)\ dy\ge \int_{\lvert x-y\rvert<ar-r} f(x-y) dy=\int_{B_{(0,ar-r)}}\ dy>0$

Hence $E-E$ contains a ball with radius $ar-r$ centered at the origin ????

Comment: Fubini's theorem might come handy.

Comment: @HuiYu can you explain in more detail ?

Comment: This is a special case of Steinhaus' theorem, which is true for Haar measure on a locally compact group. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem

Comment: $\int f*g=\mu(E)\mu(E)>0$, so the convolution is not always zero. By continuity of $f*g$ it must be positive on an open set. This open set contains the ball you are looking for.

Comment: @HuiYu is $\int f*g$ a double integral what do you use for the first equation. Translation invariance and fubini?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's choose $f$ and $g$ as you did. Then \begin{equation}
\int f*g(x)dx=\int\int f(y)g(x-y)dydx=\int f(y)\int 1_{E}(y-x)dxdy=\mu(E)\int f(y)dy.
\end{equation}We used the fact $1_E(y-x)=1_{y-E}(x)$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(y-E)$. Now $\int f=\mu(E)$ so $\int f*g=\mu(E)\mu(E)>0$.

If your $E$ is of finite measure (if it is not, just cut out a subset of finite measure by the $\sigma$-finiteness of Lebesgue measure), then $f*g$ is a continuous function. So $V:=\{f*g>0\}$ is an nonempty open set.

Now note that $x\in V$ implies $\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\neq 0$, and in particular there is $y$ such that $f(x-y)\neq 0$ and $g(y)\neq 0$. Thus $x-y\in E$ and $y\in -E$ thus $x=x-y+y\in E-E$. This shows $V\subset E-E$ thus $E-E$ contains an open set.